# How to Add Pull-To-Refresh to a Tableview "Query from Parse.com"

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, tableview, pull-to-refresh

I have an app that query data from a class in Parse.com.

I'm able to populate the table correctly.

How can i add a Pull to Refresh to refresh the tableview ?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the refresh control, making your datasource-providing class the target.
2. When the refresh action triggers, invoke the parse query code you already have working to fetch from parse.  That query must already `reloadData` when it is done.
3. Add a line to that completion block to tell your refresh control to `endRefreshing`.

EDIT - most of the time, the view controller containing the table is also the table's datasource.  If that's the case, then create the refresh control in that same view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

```
UIRefreshControl  *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(refresh:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Set the target to `self` and in that same class implement the selector refresh, which will have a signature like this:

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)control {
    // step two:  from here, invoke the same parse query code you have working
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me a Code example for the first Point ? How can i make link the refresh Control to Datasource ?